# When moving inline javascript to it's own file, the page no longer functions correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help with this...

I wrote all of my javascript code within the .html file withing the  brackets.  I need to move it to it's own file.

I have normal javascript, as well as Jquery.

Here is the header from the HTML file:

```
<head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    <title>
        title
    </title>
</head>
```

And the myScript.js file is surrounded by:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There is a small portion of my code in the myScript.js file that uses JQuery, but that functionality does not work.  However, when I have everything in one file, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I removed the HTML code from the .js file.  I was a little confused about that, but it makes sense now.

Comment: I got the code to work correctly.  I place the two script calls to the end of the HTML file, directly after the </body> tag.  It works fine now.  Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The `.js` file should only contain Javascript code. No `<script>` tags around it — that's HTML, not Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` around the code in the `myScript.js` file. Code in a .js file should be javascript - not html.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `myScript.js` should just be Javascript. No html (`<script type="text/javascript"></script>`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

from your .JS file. In JS file there should only JS code...

Answer (score 1):

When you say

"And the myScript.js file is surrounded by:"

Do you mean you've done this in your external file called myScript.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myCode=function(){
// doing stuff
};

</script>
```

Because if you have then ... DON'T! :) The  tag is not needed in an external .js file